# How to delete specific lines from a text file which are paths except .txt files using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am new to batch scripting and i was trying a new thing. 
I have a sample text file sample.txt.

It contains path of folders and files. Here is the file sample.txt:

> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Apple 1
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Apple 1\file1.txt
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Apple 2\file2.txt
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Apple 3
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Apple 4\hello.docz
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Apple 4

I want to delete the path lines from sample.txt which are just folders & other files but want to keep text files. I want the output to be stored in the same file sample.txt:

> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Apple 1\file1.txt
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Apple 2\file2.txt

Comment: There is no way of distinguishing which of the entries are files or directories without checking each line separately against your file system. All that is possible, is to parse those lines which use the extensions expected to identify a particular file type. In this case those which end with `.txt` 'should' identify text files, _but there's nothing to stop someone from giving an image file a `.txt` extension._

Answer (score 3):

```
findstr  /e /i "\.txt" "sample.txt" > "new.file"
move /y "new.file" "sample.txt"
```

Comment: Not quite - the `.` is a regex meta-character. You either need to escape the dot as `\.`, or else add the `/L` literal option.

Comment: @dbenham - tanks.

Comment: Also, you need the `/I` option to ignore case.

Comment: how do i do it if I just need all the files of all extensions except path lines ending in folders?

Comment: @dbenham ?? This does not work.
findstr  /e /i "\.*" "sample.txt" > "new.file"
move /y "new.file" "sample.txt"

Comment: @VaibhavBorkar That is an entirely different question that requires a different strategy.

Comment: @dbenham can you help me with that